# R: KM curves plot in survival package change x axis range

Tags: r, plot

I'm using the survival package to generate the KM curves for two populations but when I tried to define the xmax parameter, I am unable to extend the x-axis range from 0-15 to 0 - 50.

Here is my code:

```
 library(sm)
library(survival)
comb = read.csv("S:/Novocure/ChemoSKTime2Resp.csv", head = TRUE)
comb
survobj = with(comb, Surv(SK.response.time,Censored))
survobj

# Compare the survival distributions of nonresponders(0) and responders(1)

fitresp = survfit(survobj ~ response, data=comb)
fitresp
summary(fitresp)

# plot the survival distributions by response

plot(fitresp, xlab="Tumor Progression Time in Months", 
  ylab="% Progressed", yscale=100, col=c("red","blue"),
  main="Chemo Time to Tumor Progression Distribution", xmax = 50) 
  legend("topright", title="Chi-sq = 5.2, P = 0.0222", 
  c("Non-responders", "Responders"), fill=c("red", "blue"))
```

Comment: It is really poor form to include `rm(list = ls())` in your example code -- a naive SO user could run it in a session where they are working too.

Comment: Also, how are we supposed to access your csv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xmax` argument to `plot.survfit` appears to only shorten the range of the x-axis. To extend it, use the argument `xlim` instead:

```
plot(fitresp, xlab="Tumor Progression Time in Months", 
  ylab="% Progressed", yscale=100, col=c("red","blue"),
  main="Chemo Time to Tumor Progression Distribution", xlim = c(0,50))
```